# What is the probability of a random line segment intersect a random rectangle in a unit square?

Tags: geometry, geometric-probability

Let $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ be four random points inside the unit square, where a random point is found by generating two random numbers between 0 and 1, and taking them as the x and y coordinates.

What is the probability of the line segment $AB$ intersects the axis-aligned rectangle with opposite corners $C$ and $D$?

Comment: I think you want to refer to an axis-aligned rectangle with opposite corners $C$ and $D$.  Otherwise if $C$ is right of or above $D$ there is no rectangle as you specify.

Comment: I've updated the question, thanks!